# Makefile: How write a rule that is only executed when a certain shared object library doesn't exist?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a rule, which should only execute if a certain shared object library doesn't exist

```
$(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so: v8

v8: # to be able to build V8 only with "make v8"
    cd V8; bash V8Update.sh
```

However, `V8Update.sh` is executed every time. Here is the full `Makefile`:

```
CC=g++
V8INCLUDEDIR=V8/build/v8/include
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++0x -fPIC -I$(V8INCLUDEDIR) -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.6                               \
       -I/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward -I/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu         \
       -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed                   \
       -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/
DEPS=ProxyTypes.h $(V8INCLUDEDIR)/v8.h $(V8INCLUDEDIR)/v8-debug.h $(V8INCLUDEDIR)/v8stdint.h
ARCH=x64 # TODO: Add support for building 32-bit libraries.
LDFLAGS=-shared -lglib-2.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ #-Wl,--no-undefined
SOURCES=Exports.cpp FunctionTemplateProxy.cpp HandleProxy.cpp ObjectTemplateProxy.cpp Utilities.cpp V8EngineProxy.cpp  \
        ValueProxy.cpp
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %,$(OUTDIR)/%,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
LIBRARY=libV8_Net_Proxy.so

.PHONY: all v8 release debug makeoutdir clean copybin

all: debug copybin

v8: # to be able to build V8 only with "make v8"
    cd V8; bash V8Update.sh

release: OUTDIR=bin/Release
debug: OUTDIR=bin/Debug

release debug:
    $(MAKE) -S makeoutdir $(LIBRARY) OUTDIR=$(OUTDIR)


makeoutdir:
    mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)

clean:
    rm bin/ -rf
#   rm V8/build -rf

copybin:
    cp -a bin/Debug/*.so ../bin/Debug

$(LIBRARY): $(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -lv8-$(ARCH) -L$(OUTDIR) -o $(patsubst %,$(OUTDIR)/%,$@) $(OBJECTS)

$(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so: v8

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
v8: $(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so

$(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so:
    cd V8; bash V8Update.sh
```

You can't depend on phony target - it will be executed every time (and that is a feature, btw).

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. V8Update.sh is still invoked every time and now it's invoked twice (I guess once for release and once for debug). It only needs to be executed once because V8Update.sh generates both release and debug binaries. Additionally, in the rule `v8`, `$(OUTDIR)` is not defined as its only defined when running `debug` or `release` target.

Comment: Just noticed that when adding `ls $@` to the second rule in your answer, it actually executes `ls bin/Debug/libv8-x64`. I wonder why the `.so` suffix is missing. This explains why it's still always executed.

Comment: Also the solution for `v8` target not having `$(OUTDIR)` defined is to just to copy the command instead of making it depend on `$(OUTDIR)/libv8-$(ARCH).so`.

Comment: ARCH=x64 # TODO: Add support for building 32-bit libraries. ARCH would be 'x64   ' (spaces before '#' included). Don't use comments like that, bring it to separate line.